# Date intervals changed on the 15th of a month

Tags: sql, loops, date, intervals

I'm looking for a way to have my sql query change the dates in my query on the 15th of every month so my data pulls have a "rolling 12 months".  For example, right now, my query pulls the dates (YYYYQMM) between 2018411 and 2019410.  I have it hard coded so it looks like this:

```
Select *
From Table
WHERE Spend_Period_YYYYQMM >= 2018411 and Spend_Period_YYYYQMM <= 2019410
```

I would like to have a solution that on Dec 15th it changes the dates to 2018412 and 2019411.

I have a solution to change the dates every month like below but would like the dates to change on the 15th:

```
Spend_Period_YYYYQMM between to_char(date(current_date -  cast('13 month' as interval)),'YYYYQMM') 
                         and to_char(date(current_date -  cast('2 month' as interval)),'YYYYQMM')
```

How should I got about it

Comment: Get the 1st day of the month (e.g. `TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'M')`, add 15 days and then go on with your current calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use some [CASE clauses](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) and the [EOMONTH function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) along with GetDate() to get your desired range.

---

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = GETDATE();
select case 
    when day(@date) <= 14
        then EOMONTH(@date, -13) 
    when day(@date) >= 15
        then EOMONTH(@date, -12)
    end as RollingYearBegin
    ,case 
    when day(@date) <= 14
        then EOMONTH(@date, -2) 
    when day(@date) >= 15
        then EOMONTH(@date, -1)
    end as RollingYearEnd
into #RollingYear
```

---

Then if you need the values formatted in that specific way when you call them, you could either complicate that temp table above a bit more, or just make another little table

---

```
    Select cast(concat(datepart(yyyy,RollingYearBegin),  datepart(q,RollingYearBegin), datepart(MM,RollingYearBegin)) as bigint) as YearBegin
,cast(concat(datepart(yyyy,RollingYearEnd),  datepart(q,RollingYearEnd), datepart(MM,RollingYearEnd)) as bigint) as YearEnd
into #YYYYQMM
From #RollingYear
```

---

Then, in your query, it would be:

```
Select *
From Table
WHERE Spend_Period_YYYYQMM BETWEEN (Select YearBegin from #YYYYQMM) AND (Select YearEnd from #YYYYQMM)
```